# Dell Latitude E5550 network problem

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, dell, ethernet

I am a new user. So I have installed Ubuntu 22 LTS and it doesn't connect to Wi Fi SSID and my ethernet cable properly I have it says connected but showing a question mart on the wi fi sign and do the same with the ethernet cable and I can't access the internet. I have also windows 10 on my device and it doesn't show this problem I guess it's a driver problem since in the installation process it showed the same problem but when i opened dell support i found no internet adapters driver for ubuntu in my device page.

Comment: Please attach output of this terminal command: `lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -i "net"`